# Eclipse stopped giving default proposals

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using Eclipse to develop Android applications

I have a weird problem where Eclipse has stopped giving default proposals. Previously it was working fine and but now not working.

Cleaned the workspace but no improvement in the behaviour.

[image]

Comment: Oops....Siva ? What do you mean by default proposals. that way we can understand your eclipse issue

Comment: @RamakishnaBalla proposals like if I am using a class object then I need to get variables or objects associated with that object

Comment: see if compile is ok as of now. Looks like you stressed the eclipse too much :) ...give it some rest and restart it after a break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem recently, right after having upgraded my Eclipse.

Open your preferences (Window/Preferences/Java/Editor/Content Assist/Advanced) and ensure that "Java Proposals" is checked: [image]

If this was fine already, check the level above (Window/Preferences/Java/Editor/Content Assist), as follows: [image]

**EDIT (as commented below)** Should both settings be correct, Eclipse is maybe a little overwhelmed. Try to restart it and wait for the worskpace tasks (build, compile, highlighting, ...) to finish properly. It often works.

Comment: Thanks for your response but this doesn't worked for me... actually I used to get proposals till morning but for past few hours I am not getting

Comment: And your preferences are according to what is shown above? (they were not changed accidentally?)

Comment: Eclipse is sometimes a bit tired and needs some sleep :) I'm quite sure you've tried but just to confirm: have you restarted it, and did all the worskpace tasks finish properly? (compile OK, highlighting OK, etc?)

Comment: oops I didn't restarted it... didn't check `compile`... will do these task will update you.. thanks

Comment: Nothing is working for me as of now.. I think I am stressing it toomuch.. will give it a break.. will accept as answer once it is working for me. for now +1 for help

Comment: Cheers! And it is absolutely legitimate that you don't accept an answer that was not proven yet :) Should the problem occur after restart, please update your question with a screenshot of your Eclipse, in Java Perspective, Errors tab selected. This may help a lot.

Comment: gave some rest to the eclipse and now working.. thanks

Comment: Eclipse takes care of the programmers' health :)

Comment: @shlublu... again problem started... can you please help me in getting the permanent solution

Comment: I'm not sure as it sounds environment-specific. Looks like your Eclipse is overloaded. You may have too many projects open at the same time, and/or a machine not powerful enough to handle such a load. At some points, Eclipse breaks (I have to restart mine once a day when I'm working on stuff that involve opening more than 5 projects at a time. The effect is different: autocompletion is still working but other things break, like USB connections or resources compile).

Comment: If I create a new project it works... but when I open exisiting project it is not showing proposals... any change need to be done in existing project?

Comment: I don't think so. It would be good that you show a screenshot of your Eclipse, in Java Perspective, Errors tab selected. This may help a lot

Comment: At the bottom of the screen, usually. Right under the code, you have "Console", "Problems", "LogCat", etc. "Problems" will be interesting here

Comment: There are `problems` but only warnings... are those need to be concentrated?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I expected errors to be messing Eclipse.